# How to obtain a customized (and friendly) url using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Say I have a URL like `http://abc.com/index.php?cat=37&subsubcat=0&subcat=199&page=product_detail&product_id=1661`

Can I use `.htaccess` to redirect/rewrite this to a URL like `http://abc.com/simplerName`?

I found quite a few posts on SO that ask for friendly URLs, but I want to take it a step further, i.e. I'd like to specify what the **subfolder** name should be (in the above example, it's "`simplerName`"). Now I've got 10 URLs that I want to customize and I'm totally cool with specifying 10 rules for each URL.

But I'm not sure how to achieve this using `.htaccess`. Is this even possible?

Comment: Yes, you surely can use `.htaccess` to redirect/rewrite the URL. You can start by reading [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to achieve this.

Comment: I am fully aware that .htaccess can be used to rewrite a URL. What I'd like to know is specifying the destination subfolder instead of just making it url friendly. I've gone through the other questions here and some were close, but not duplicates of what I'm asking.

Comment: What exactly do you want `simplerName` to be? `/subfolder/37/0/199/product_detail/1661/`?

Comment: I was simplerName to be exactly that. So redirect a url like http://abc.com/index.php?cat=37&subsubcat=0&subcat=199&page=product_detail&product_id=1661   to http://abc.com/simplerName. For the other 9 URLs I need to do this for, I want to specify what the subfolder is going to be. Note that the subfolder doesn't exist and it's just for the friendliness aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using non-existing "subfiolders" to indicate which rule should match what, this is going to be pretty straight-forward:

You want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /index.php?cat=$1&subsubcat=$2&subcat=$3&page=$4&product_id=$5 [L]

RewriteRule ^/?something-else/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /index.php?something=$1&subsub=$2&sub=$3&page=$4&something_id=$5 [L]
```

etc.

You'll then need to change all the URLs that you serve to the friendly looking ones instead of the ones with the query string.

Comment: Seems pretty simple... what does the [L] do? And I'll test this right now...thanks, Jon.

Comment: @Ray the `[L]` flag tells the rewrite engine to stop the rewriting process *for the current iteration*. Though the rules will loop, it stops rewriting for the current iteration if the `RewriteRule` is applied.

Comment: so to test this out and using my example, is this what I'm supposed to be using?

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?simplerName/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /index.php?cat=37&subsubcat=0&subcat=199&page=product_detail&product_id=1661 [L]

Doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @Ray I put that rule in a blank htaccess file and went to `http://localhost/simplerName/1/2/3/4/5/` and it served me the content at `/index.php?cat=37&subsubcat=0&subcat=199&page=product_detail&product_id=1661`. Note that the 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 never made it to the rewritten query string because your rule doesn't use backreferences ($1, $2, $3, etc).